# Multiple User-Meta Values in One User-Meta Key

Tags: user-meta, array

Currently, I am adding user metadata with the key `position_name` and a string value representing a user's position, such that I can retrieve a user's position by way of a call similar to:

```
$position = get_user_meta(22, 'position_name', true);
```

This works perfectly for one position per user, but I'd like to be able to associate each user with several positions. Would adding a serialized array within the `position_name` field be an appropriate way of achieving this?

I hope that makes sense..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check out [the documentation for the `update_user_meta()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta), you'll note that the `$meta_value` parameter already accepts objects and arrays, so you can simply save a user's positions in an array without any additional effort:

```
update_user_meta(
    22,
    'position_names',
    array(
        'Khaleesi of the Great Grass Sea',
        'Breaker of Chains',
        'Mother of Dragons'
    )
);
```

The user meta functions already take care of serializing and unserializing the array for you (converting it to and from a string, respectively). Note that [the documentation for `get_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) specifies that the last parameter `$single` denotes whether to just return one meta-value directly, or return all values in an array. You're looking to get all of the `position_name`s, so you should pass `false` as `$single` or omit the argument entirely (in which case it will default to `false`):

```
$position_names = get_user_meta( 22, 'position_names' );

//$position_names[0] === 'Khaleesi of the Great Grass Sea'
//$position_names[1] === 'Breaker of Chains'
//$position_names[2] === 'Mother of Dragons'
```

> #### Note
>
> If you use `update_user_meta()` in the future to store an object (or an associative array), know that you may run into [bug #9640](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9640)

Comment: Fantastic! I wasn't so much asking if it was possible, but more asking if it was considered a reasonable practice. Thank you kindly!

Comment: Well it's certainly a common enough occurrence that the core WP contributors thought it reasonable to include support for it ;) . In general I would say this is a perfectly reasonable solution for most problems in this scope, but if you're working with much larger objects/amounts of data it would probably be prudent to create your own database table to store it, so as to avoid the overhead associated with meta-data.